# Exception:Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

**Actually I am trying to do hibernate logging. This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
              "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
              "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  

    <hibernate-configuration>  

        <session-factory>  
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/temp</property>  
            <property name="connection.username">root</property>  
            <property name="connection.password">root</property>  
            <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
        <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>  
        </session-factory>   
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

**Here is the exception...**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at com.subhas.mypackage.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:13)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection refused: connect Nested exception: Connection refused: connect
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 2 more
```

**this is employee.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
     "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

     <hibernate-mapping>  
      <class name="com.subhas.mypackage.Employee" table="emp1000">  
        <id name="id">  
         <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
        </id>  

        <property name="firstName"></property>  
        <property name="lastName"></property>  

      </class>  

     </hibernate-mapping>
```

**this is my main class**

```
public class StoreData {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //creating configuration object
    Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

     //creating session factory object
     SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();


     //creating session object
     Session session=factory.openSession();


     //creating transaction object
     Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();

     Employee employee=new Employee();

     employee.setId(5000);
     employee.setfName("Subhas");
     employee.setlName("Gupta");


     //persisting the object
     session.persist(employee);

     //commit the transaction object
     transaction.commit();
     session.close();

     System.out.println("Data Saved Successfully");


    }

  }
```

I am unable to find a perfect solution for this. Could someone help me.? Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the `:3306` port of your connection string.

Comment: @ sp00m i have tried removing after the port but still it's having the same Exception.

Comment: i think there is an issue with the DOCTYPE tag in you hibernate.cfg.xml file. That is the reason the parser is not able to recognize and parse the xml file. can you add the correct definition for the DOCTYPE above. check the hibernate.org website for same

Comment: What version of hibernate do you have?

Comment: @BheshGurung i am using Hibernate-Version: 3.2.1.ga

Comment: Are you sure about the DB name `temp`, table name `emp1000`, and both username and password `root` ..?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the DOCTYPE to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but i think you are missing BasicConfiguration.configure() for some log4J configuration then you would not face log4J initailization exception.

Answer (score 0):

My friend Error just cause an not proper dialect selected. Please make sure it is correct and you also need to add column property in mapping file.

```
<class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">

    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="assigned"></generator>
    </id>

    <property name="name" column="NAME"></property>
    <property name="mobile" column="MOBILE"></property>
    <property name="email" column="EMAIL"></property>

</class>
```

am sure your error get resolved with this...