# Hibernate program giving error

Tags: hibernate

I have create an Hibernate Application project but I am getting the following error when I run the program

```
  log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
 Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not    parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
at SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:11)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection timed out: connect Nested exception: Connection timed out: connect
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
... 3 more
```

Below is my Hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
     "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
     "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 
 <session-factory>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sys</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">newpassword</property>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
   <property name="hibernate.default_schema">sys</property>
   <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <mapping resource="emp.hbm.xml"></mapping>
</session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain what specific question you have regarding this error is?

Comment: When i try to run the hibernate application i get this exception

Comment: Please see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681589/exceptioncould-not-parse-configuration-hibernate-cfg-xml

Comment: No luck with the link

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a log4j configuration file to your classpath. It can be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

As of [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).